# How to make graphs that avoid certain sub-graphs and have as many edges as possible?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, math-software, perfect-powers, extremal-graph-theory

The other day, I needed to create a graph with $10$ vertices, $16$ edges, and which didn't have a loop of four vertices, $C_4$, or a daisy-chain of three $3$-cliques (see picture) as sub-graphs. Turns out there is one such graph up to isomorphism (two butterfly sub-graphs with four edges spanning between them). And any graph on $10$ vertices with $17$ or more edges will contain a copy of $C_4$ or a daisy-chain of three $3$ cliques. So the one graph I found is the unique *maximally edged* (proper term?) graph that avoids the previously mentioned sub-graphs.

Now I want to do a similar search. I want to find all graphs (up to isomorphism) with $11$ vertices that have as many edges as possible and avoid the three graphs in the picture below. I wrote a [python program](https://replit.com/@ChristianWolird/PowerCouples) to solve this question on $10$ vertices; but it's slow and unsophisticated so it won't scale well and I'm hoping for a better solution.

This problem comes up when solving a question I learned from Neil Sloane on [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPoh5C9CcI8): given $n$ distinct integers, how many of their pair-wise sums can be powers of two? Turns out that if you treat the $n$ integers as vertices in a graph and add an edge between any two whose sum is a power of two, then such graphs must avoid the three sub-graphs in the picture below. For instance, with this graph generation approach, we can solve the case for $n=10$ integers/vertices proving that at most $15$ of their pair-wise sums can powers of two (see question/answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536454)). I'm hoping to write some math software that automates the tedious parts of this approach to find the optimal solutions (if everything goes well) to $n\le 50$.

In general then, I'm wondering: given a set of sub-graphs, how does one efficiently construct all graphs (up to isomorphism) that have as many edges as possible and avoid those sub-graphs? I figure the time-complexity here might be exponential in the number of vertices. But if $10$ vertices is solvable, I'd like to know what else is in reach.

My only optimization for the $10$ vertex case was to assume that any solution would have at least one $3$-clique. So my program, which brute-force built up all possible graphs edge by edge, checking for bad sub-graphs as it went, started with a $3$-clique to cut down the search space. I didn't check for graph isomorphisms while doing the construction; just when printing out solutions so there's likly a lot of time savings there.

[image: Relevant subgraphs]

Comment: While I can't say for certain, I suspect that this is not an easy problem in general. I haven't read it in full but my masters supervisor's PhD thesis was on a closely related problem so you might be able to get something from it (see here http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maskat/Papers/eh.pdf). However I don't know if this will be of much help to you, apologies that I can't be of more help.

Comment: I'm not sure you could do much better in terms of time complexity since, as you said, graph isomorphism is NP-complete. You might be able to achieve some speed-up for some specific classes of excluded subgraphs though. I guess you could maybe try using a package like SageMath where the code is optimized and do some benchmarks to see what you can possibly expect.

Comment: Are you positive about needing to avoid that last graph? I can construct that with powers of two, with the $C_5$ being, starting from the center of the left bowtie: $(9, -7, 11, -3, 7)$. Given this builds on a previous post of yours, I'll assume you can identify the remaining vertices. (Note this is still not maximal on $10$ vertices IIRC)

Comment: I'll second converting into SageMath. I haven't dealt with its graph-theoretic functions but it has a lot of optimized stuff ready, you won't need your own class definition to start.

Comment: @EricSnyder Wow! I managed to find the remaining vertices for your solution. Looks like I'll have to double check my work! If you can add in two more edges to that sub-graph (from the far top right vertex to the far top left and from the far bottom right to the far bottom left) then we will have a solution with $16$ sums instead of $15$. I might have used those last two edges in my scratch work and forgotten. I got ambitious and thought I could trim the graph down a couple edges and still retain its impossibility.

Comment: @ChrisWolird I'm pretty sure there are no further connections there though to add to those $14$. We end up with $23, -5$ on the left and $-1,3$ on the far right. So the $10$-vertex solution avoids this, but not more general solutions.

Comment: Conjecture: for $n \neq 3,5$, the (or one of the) maximal solution can be found using a continuous set of odd numbers. There are certainly other primitive solutions, but the ones that should be mathematically "easiest" to add a single vertex to and get $3-5$ new edges will be those with the greatest concentration of small values.

Comment: Hey, so I've actually still have been working on this a bit lately. While that last graph you drew isn't necessarily excluded, this one is: https://imgur.com/a/kTubQTE .... I don't yet have a proof sketch for my conjecture above, but it *feels* right heuristically.  And yes, this stuff seems to be nice and easy in SageMath.

Comment: @EricSnyder I've been writing a software library to automate both the process of finding these kinds of graphs, and proving their unsolvability. If you wanna chat, you can ping at my work email (white.stone.society "at" gmail.com) or on discord (WhiteStoneJazz#8367) if you're on that. I might be able to layout a proof your graph is unsolvable too.